# svg drop-shadow on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have a `drop-shadow filter` applied to an `svg` object on my page. I apply the drop-shadow using some inline styling on the element

```
<style>
    .historicUploadDonuts {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 3.5px 3.5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65));
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 3.5px 3.5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65));
    }
</style>
```

This works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

How can I get the same effect on Internet Explorer 11? I cannot use `box-shadow` as this does not apply the shadow to the donut but the containing `div`